# Understanding the definition of t IJ when I AND J are ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

if I is ideal and J is ideal then

$$IJ=\left\{ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i b_i\mid a_i\in I, b_i\in J \right\}$$

i am not undetsnaging the defination of it, what is n some n that belong to N? n = |I| or |J|? according to this definitiation it look like that |I| = |J| so each ideals inside some ring have the same size?

Comment: Yes, $n\in\mathbb N$.  No, $n$ has nothing to do with the size of $I$ or $J$, it ranges over all integers.  I don't know why you think it means $|I|=|J|$. Both of them could be infinite. You should also add "$n\in\mathbb N$" inside the braces.

Comment: It words, this says "The set of all finite sums of products $ij$ where $i\in I$ and $j\in J$"

Comment: Form a set consisting of all the possible products of elements of $I$ with elements of $J$: $$P=\{ab\;|\;a\in I, b\in J\}.$$ Form another set that consists of  all the possible finite sums of elements of the set $P$. What you then get is the set $IJ:$ $$IJ=\left\{\sum_{finite}ab \;|\; ab\in P\right\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this looks clearer:
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left\{a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n: a_1,\ldots,a_n \in I \,\text{ and }\,b_1,\ldots,b_n \in J\right\}
$$

Comment: again from your defination it look like |I| = |j|, what about define it in case when I,J are finite? and has diffrent sizes?

Comment: No. The definition has nothing to do with the cardinalities of $I$ and $J$, finite or not, equal or not.

Comment: @idokahana Do you think the $a_i$ are somehow an exhaustive list of elements of $I$? It isn't.